# How to assign custom colors to bars in a D3.js bar chart?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am using LeafletJs and D3js to put a bar chart in a Leaflet popup window.

How can I assign a custom color for each ethnic group bar? I want to assign the custom colors within the D3 code because I can't modify the original dataset. [Link](http://arsh23.github.io/ogmda/map.html)

Thanks.

```
var onEachFeature = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

colors = d3.scale.category20()
var div = $('<div id="chart"><h3>Ethnic Group Distribution</h3><svg/><h4>Additional details:</h4>Extra stuff here</div>')[0];

var popup = L.popup({
    minWidth: 500,
    minHeight: 350
}).setContent(div);

layer.bindPopup(popup);

var values = feature.properties;

var data = [{
    name: "Pashtun",
    value: values["Pashtun"]
}, {
    name: "Tajik",
    value: values["Tajik"]
}, {
    name: "Uzbek",
    value: values["Uzbek"]
}, {
    name: "Turkmen",
    value: values["Turkmen"]
}, {
    name: "Hazara",
    value: values["Hazara"]
}, {
    name: "Baloch",
    value: values["Baloch"]
}, {
    name: "Kirghiz",
    value: values["Kirghiz"]
}, {
    name: "Nuristani",
    value: values["Nuristani"]
}, {
    name: "Aimak",
    value: values["Aimak"]
}, {
    name: "Arab",
    value: values["Arab"]
}, {
    name: "Pashaye",
    value: values["Pashaye"]
}, {
    name: "Sadat",
    value: values["Sadat"]
}, {
    name: "Qezelbash",
    value: values["Qezelbash"]
}];

var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 80,
        left: 30
    },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    barWidth = width / data.length;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return "";
    })

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)

var svg = d3.select(div)
    .select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .classed("chart", true);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (i * barWidth + 5) + ",0)";
    });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
            return y(d.value);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth - 10)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        if (!isNaN(d.value)) {
            return height - y(d.value);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    })
    .attr("fill",function(d,i){return colors(i)})


bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return -height - 70;
    })
    .attr("y", barWidth / 2)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(270)")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

};

var geojson = L.geoJson(myData, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Dataset Test:

```
var afghanDistrictsSample = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "Pashtun": 0.43,
        "Tajik": 0.12,
        "Uzbek": 0.05,
        "Turkmen": 0.00,
        "Hazara": 0.00,
        "District": "Argo",
        "Province": "Kandahar"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [61.69921875, 32.08257455954592],
                [61.69921875, 32.879587173066305],
                [62.666015625, 32.879587173066305],
                [62.666015625, 32.08257455954592],
                [61.69921875, 32.08257455954592]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.32,
        "Tajik": 0.20,
        "Uzbek": 0.01,
        "Turkmen": 0.02,
        "Hazara": 0.00,
        "District": "Jurm",
        "Province": "Farah"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [62.75390625, 32.95336814579932],
                [62.75390625, 33.76088200086917],
                [63.69873046874999, 33.76088200086917],
                [63.69873046874999, 32.95336814579932],
                [62.75390625, 32.95336814579932]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.05,
        "Tajik": 0.50,
        "Uzbek": 0.21,
        "Turkmen": 0.00,
        "Hazara": 0.00,
        "District": "Ragh",
        "Province": "Ghor"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [63.74267578125, 33.54139466898275],
                [63.74267578125, 34.43409789359469],
                [65.14892578125, 34.43409789359469],
                [65.14892578125, 33.54139466898275],
                [63.74267578125, 33.54139466898275]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.00,
        "Tajik": 0.01,
        "Uzbek": 0.10,
        "Turkmen": 0.20,
        "Hazara": 0.40,
        "District": "Highan",
        "Province": "Kabul"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [64.53369140625, 35.15584570226544],
                [64.53369140625, 35.94243575255426],
                [65.56640625, 35.94243575255426],
                [65.56640625, 35.15584570226544],
                [64.53369140625, 35.15584570226544]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.00,
        "Tajik": 0.01,
        "Uzbek": 0.20,
        "Turkmen": 0.30,
        "Hazara": 0.04,
        "District": "Nusay",
        "Province": "Kunduz"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [65.58837890625, 33.30298618122413],
                [65.58837890625, 34.32529192442733],
                [66.90673828125, 34.32529192442733],
                [66.90673828125, 33.30298618122413],
                [65.58837890625, 33.30298618122413]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.20,
        "Tajik": 0.00,
        "Uzbek": 0.00,
        "Turkmen": 0.10,
        "Hazara": 0.20,
        "District": "Zebak",
        "Province": "Logar"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [65.98388671875, 34.72355492704219],
                [65.98388671875, 35.53222622770337],
                [66.95068359374999, 35.53222622770337],
                [66.95068359374999, 34.72355492704219],
                [65.98388671875, 34.72355492704219]
            ]
        ]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "Pashtun": 0.10,
        "Tajik": 0.10,
        "Uzbek": 0.28,
        "Turkmen": 0.10,
        "Hazara": 0.00,
        "District": "Wakhan",
        "Province": "Nimruz"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [67.32421875, 34.43409789359469],
                [67.32421875, 35.42486791930558],
                [68.37890625, 35.42486791930558],
                [68.37890625, 34.43409789359469],
                [67.32421875, 34.43409789359469]
            ]
        ]
    }
}]
};
```

Comment: I din't understand: you can't modify the `var data`? If you can, it's simple: for each object, after `name` and `value`, just create a pair `color: #something`, and then `.attr("fill", function(d){return d.color});`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the built-in categorical colors...

```
colors = d3.scale.category20()
```

...you could try using an ordinal scale...

```
var colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(['Pashtun','Tajik','Uzbek', 'Turkmen', 'Hazara', 'Baloch','Kirghiz','Nuristani','Aimak', 'Arab','Pashaye','Sadat','Qezelbash'])
    .range(['red', 'white', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'lime', 'black', 'navy', 'silver', 'skyblue', 'purple', 'olive' ])
```

...then modify your code to do a lookup on the name:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(d.name) })
```

I didn't test the code, but you could read more about ordinal scales here if it doesn't work:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

Alternatively, you could simply add a class to the element...

```
.attr("class", function(d, i) { return 'bar_' + d.name} )
```

... and class it in your CSS:

```
.bar_Pashtun { fill: blue }
```

Comment: awesome idea. Thank you! I'll report back.